# Finding a basis for the set $S$ of all functions of the form $A\sin(x) + B\cos(x)$

Tags: functions

I'm not really sure where to begin honestly. I understand that a basis for a subspace is a set of vectors that span the space $S$ along with being linearly independent. I understand how to find basis of a matrix with numbers in it (column space, row space, null space, left null space), but I don't know how to proceed with finding a basis for functions of the form stated above. Also, $A$ and $B$ are real numbers. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try and show that $\{\sin x, \cos x\}$ is a linearly independent set.

Comment: @Sebastiano Please do not make cosmetic edits to old questions! That moves them to the active queue and wastes the time of folks like me who follow that queue. Wastes your time too.

Answer (score 1):

$f_1=\sin(x)$ and $f_2=\cos(x)$ form such a basis as all $f=A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$ is automatically a linear combination of $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Answer (score 1):

The basis is $\{\sin(x),\cos(x)\}$

Given any $A\sin(x)+B\cos(x)$, this is obviously a linear combination of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

Now to prove that $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are linearly independent, you would compute the determinant of the Wronskian matrix, which then you get $\det(W) = -1 \neq 0$. So  $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are linearly independent
thus {$\sin(x),\cos(x)$} is a basis.